# SASS nesting best practise?

Tags: css, sass

Is it mandatory to nest all child element to it's parent? Please take a look at my example code. I saw some articles, they warned to nest child elements only to 4 levels. But here I wrapped all childs to it's parent. Is it ok to code sass like this format?

```
<div class="col-md-3 left-side">
 <div class="profile-info">
    <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
    <p>Header</p>
    <span>2 minutes ago</span>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="ads">
 <h4>Advertisements</h4>
 <img src="img/ad1.jpg" alt="">
 <p>Grab your book !!!</p>
    <img src="img/ad2.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Hurry up. Limited offers !!!</p>
    <img src="img/ad3.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Grab your book !!!</p>
    <img src="img/ad4.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Hurry up. Limited offers !!!</p>
    </div>
</div>

.left-sidebar{
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    .ads{
        img{
            width:100%;
        }
        h4{
            margin-top:45px;
            margin-top: 45px;
        font-weight: 600;
        }
        p{
            margin-top: 5px;
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-bottom: 22px;
        }
    }
    .profile-info{
        @include basic_style;
        padding-top: 31px;
        .info{
            padding-top: 28px;
            padding-left: 16px;
            display: inline-block;
            @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-left: 0px;
                text-align: center;
                display: block;
            }
        }
        img{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            float: left;
            @media only screen and (max-width: 440px){
                width: 85px;
                height: 85px;
            }
            @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
                display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
                float: none;
            }
        }
        p{
            @include post_title;
        }
        span{
            @include sub_header;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem of this code is  that you can't use `.ads` or `.profile-info` blocks in *right* sidebar or somewhere else. Your code is context depended.

To improve situation you can read about [BEM](http://getbem.com/) (block element modificator).

In your case at first you should remove `.left-sidebar` selector. Second, tad selectors are not good, so add class names to your inner spans, images and paragraphs.

Your code will look like:

```
.left-sidebar {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.ads {
    .img {
        width:100%;
    }

    .h4 { // .h4 is just an example, write some more meaningful name
        margin-top:45px;
        margin-top: 45px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .p {
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-bottom: 22px;
    }
}

// styles for .profile-info
```

But this scss generates unnecessary second level selectors like `.ads .img {}`. You can follow the BEM methodology to write only first level selectors.

Scss:

```
.ads {
    &__img {
        width:100%;
    }

    &__h4 {
        margin-top:45px;
        margin-top: 45px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    &__p {
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-bottom: 22px;
    }
}
```

Css output:

```
.ads__img {
  width: 100%;
}
.ads__h4 {
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.ads__p {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
```

---

**Summary**

Don't nest all child element to it's parent. Write more reusable and context-independent code.